# Python, Pandas DF. Take number from a string and add it to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, facebook-insights

I got a pandas dataframe where one of the columns have values that look like this:

```
>>> df['video_p25_watched_actions']
[{'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '137520'}]
```

I would like to extract the value number, and add it to a new column, so expected result would be:

```
Index |           video_p25_watched_actions                | p25
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0     | [{'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '137520'}] | 137520
```

I've created a google sheet with some raw data to show how it wanted it to look like:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aJDiXFyUIb9gZCA1-pPDxciPQWv0vcCairY-pkdGg_A/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try this: `import json df['p25'] = df['video_p25_watched_actions'].apply(lambda x : json.loads(x[0])['value'])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['value']= df['video_p25_watched_actions'].replace(regex=True,to_replace='[^0-9]',value=' ')
```

to get only the value from df['video_p25_watched_actions'] and other letters would be replaced by space

Comment: Please add context around why this code works so that the answer can be more useful.

Comment: This seems to just result in a copy of the column, without removing anything

Comment: This was almost the answer! I fixed it now. Needed astype(str) . `df['value'] = test_df['video_p25_watched_actions'].astype(str).replace(regex=True,to_replace='[^0-9]',value='')`

Answer (score 0):

since all rows in the column has the same structure, you can use this

```
df['new_column'] = df['video_p25_watched_actions'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(e for e in x.split(":")[2] if e.isalnum()))
```

Comment: This returns error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'